# Finding next palindromic date

Tags: java, date, palindrome

So, I'm trying to write a program which takes a date in "mmddyyyy" format as input and returns the next palindromic date (actually it returns the year, which could be reversed and prepended to itself). The below is my code: It's giving right results "AS FAR AS I KNOW". Now, I kind of feel the code is both buggy and has logical loopholes. Ignoring the fact that I'm sticking strictly to "mmddyyyy" input format (and hence some hardcoding), what do you think the code is missing?

```
public class NextPalindromeYear {
  // Date in mmddyyyy format
  //12032014
  public int nextPalindromeYear(String date) {
    char[] dateArr = date.toCharArray();
    int[] dateIntArr = new int[dateArr.length];
    int[] numberOfDays = {31,28,31,30,31,30,31,31,30,31,30,31};
    for(int i=0; i < dateArr.length;i++) {
      dateIntArr[i] = dateArr[i] - '0';
    }
    int month = dateIntArr[0] * 10 + dateIntArr[1];
    int day = dateIntArr[2] * 10 + dateIntArr[3];
    int year = 0;int pow = 1;
    for(int i= 7; i > 3; i--) {
      year += dateIntArr[i] * pow ;
      pow *= 10;
    }
    int givenYear = year;
    System.out.println("Month is " + month);
    System.out.println("Date is " + day);
    while(true) {
      System.out.println("Year is " + year);
      int split1 = year / 100;
      int split2 = year % 100;
      split1 = ((split1 % 10) * 10 ) + (split1/10);
      split2 = ((split2 % 10) * 10 ) + (split2/10);

      System.out.println("Split 1 is " + split1);
      System.out.println("Split 2 is " + split2);
      if(split1 >31 || split2 > 11) {
        year++;
        continue;
      }
      if(year%4 == 0) {
        numberOfDays[1] = 29;
      }
      else {
        numberOfDays[1] = 28;
      }
      if(numberOfDays[split2] >= split1) {
        if(year == givenYear) {
          if(!(split1 >= day && split2 > month)) {
            year++;
            continue;
          }
        }
        return year; 
      }
      year++;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Are you asking us to test your code for you?

Comment: No no. Not at all. To see if the logic is right or has any loopholes in the algorithm! Not sure if this is allowed on SO. Apologize if it isn't. Will put it on Review.

Comment: Umm, "see if the logic is right or has any loopholes in the algorithm" sounds to me a lot like testing.  Also, I don't know whether codereview is right or not.  It's for code that works, but could possibly be written better.  The question is - does this code work?  If not, tell us in what way it doesn't.  If it does, then, yes, maybe codereview.

Comment: `if (year%4 == 0)` is wrong for the [Gregorian calendar](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leap_year#Algorithm).

Comment: Since there are less than 10000 month/day combinations and the years are unconstrained, why not just generate an exhaustive list of all dates in a given format, filter via simple `isValidDate` and `isPalindrome` predicates, sort them by their ddmmyyyy order, and then look in that list for the input and get the next element.

Comment: @MikeSamuel Oh missed to take care of that %400 for centuries! Will do that. And your other method is more elegant I guess. I'll do that.